# Detecting aborted requests in a HttpServlet

Tags: http, servlets, abort

Is there a way to find out if a HttpServletRequest is aborted?

I'm writing an instant browser application (some kind of chat): The clients asks for new events in a loop using AJAX-HTTP-Requests. The server (Tomcat) handles the requests in a HttpServlet. If there are no new events for this client, the server delays the reply until a new event arrives or a timeout occurs (30sec).

Now I want to identify clients that are no longer polling. Therefore, I start a kick-Timer at the end of a request which is stopped when a new request arrives. If the client closes the browser window the TCP-Connection is closed and the HTTP-Request is aborted.

**Problem:** The client does not run into the kick-Timeout because the Servlet still handles the event request - sleeping and waiting for an event or timeout.

It would be great if I could somehow listen for connection abort events and then notify the waiting request in order to stop it. But I couldn't find anything like that in the HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse...

Comment: What API/framework are you using to handle async requests and/or HTTP pushing? Your question sounds/reads very weird, because that's not how the standard Servlet API normally works, so I guessed that you're using some API/framework on top of that to achieve this (e.g. Comet, Atmosphere, Servlet 3.0 async, etc). It's either that, or you're doing things completely wrong.

Comment: I'm not using any framework. It is as simple as this:

::::::: UpdateServlet doGet-Method
(1) gets updateClient from session
(2) gets List<Event> from updateClient
(3) Prints encoded events.

::::::: UpdateClient getEvents-method
(1) waits if no events are waiting
(2) returns the events

::::::: UpdateClient addEvent-method
(1) adds the event to a list
(2) notifies waiting threads

The requests are processed concurrently in different Threads.

Comment: This works pretty fine and instant. :-)

Comment: Regardless, the terminology in your question is definitely confusing.

Answer (score 3):

This probably won't help the OP any more, but it might help others trying to detect aborted HTTP connections in HttpServlet in general, as I was having a similar problem and finally found an answer.

The key is that when the client cancels the request, normally the only way for the server to find out is to send some data back to the client, which will fail in that case. I wanted to detect when a client stops waiting for a long computation on server, so I ended up periodically writing a single character to response body through `HttpServletResponse`'s writer. To force sending the data to the client, you must call `HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer()`, which throws `ClientAbortException` if the connection is aborted.

Comment: There is no such exception in the servlet api itself. So this is non-portable and implementation specific. There is a `org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException` for example in tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using some sort of thread-notification (Semaphores or Object.wait) to hold and release the Servlet threads. How about adding a timeout (~10s) to the wait, then somehow checking whether the connection is still alive and then continuing the wait for another 10s, if the connection is still there.

I don't know whether there are reliable ways to poll the "liveness" of the connection (e.g. resp.getOutputStream not throwing an Exception) and if so, which way is the best (most reliable, least CPU intense).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like having waiting requests could degrade the performance of your system pretty quickly.  The threads that respond to requests would get used up fast if requests are held open.  You could try completing all requests (and returning "null" to your clients if there is no message), and having a thread on the back-end that keeps track of how long it's been since clients have polled.  The thread could mark a client as being inactive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am aware of this disadvantage of open connections. The problem is, I want the clients to be informed really quickly when events arrive. If I didn't use the waiting approach the polling interval would have to be small. This again would result in a lot of traffic...

Comment: Ah I see.  There may be a way to check for aborts (sorry, I don't know for sure).  A push technology such as Comet, or something that wraps Comet, seems ideal.

Comment: Yes, I'm basically trying to implement this concept by myself in order to have more flexibility. The instant aspect works fine, but the on/off-awareness lags the awareness for abort. Thanks for your comments. :-)